# prevent user from pairing any new bluetooth devices

Tags: bluetooth

I have a bluetooth installed on my pc because my headphones are bluetooth.

I want to know if there is a way I can lock down my pc so that my sister can't add new bluetooth devices to REMOTELY mess with my stuff. I'm about to chop her hand off.

It seems strange I have phone compatible hid devices installed for example.

Comment: If you are leaving the computer unsupervised, set up a standard (non-admin) userid and use that. That will stop anything requiring installation. Many devices do not require installation so for these, you would have to disable Bluetooth except when you need it.

Comment: i have. I think they've installed a key logger or something it seems they can always guess my passwords.

Comment: Would it be easier tif I just kill them

Comment: Change your Windows password to be much stronger, scan for viruses, and then do not leave it unsupervised.